# Tensorflow different dropout configuration for one gradient update

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement the PI-Model for Semi-Supervised learning
introduced in [1].

To calculate the loss function, two forward passes through the network with the
same data are needed, whereby in each forward pass the data is modified using
stochastic augmentation. 
Additionally, dropout is used, and in each of the two passes
a different selection of neurons should be dropped out.

I am not quite sure how to implement the required dropout mechanism.

When I concatenate two differently augmented batches as input to my network,
such that one batch contains now two different augmentations of the data.
Is there maybe a way to add two "parallel" `tf.nn.dropout` layers where a dropout layer is needed, and somehow define that for the first half of
the batch the first should be used and for the second one the second?
Splitting again the output of the network should then give the result
of the two "separate" runs.

An alternative would be to really use two separate `session.run` calls,
with the two different data augmentations. However, I am not quite sure
how I could then properly perform a gradient update.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02242

Comment: Do you want a keras answer or a tensorflow answer? It seems you're using only tensorflow.

Comment: For constructing parts of the network I am using Keras (ConvLayers, PoolingLayers, etc.) however for training, data feeding etc. I use custom Tensorflow Code and no Keras routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.split()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) to split the batch into two halves, feed each half through a [`tf.layers.dropout()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout) separately, and then re-concatenate them with [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat). Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
splitted = tf.split( batch, 2, axis = 0 )
first_half = tf.dropout( splitted[ 0 ], rate = 0.5 )
second_half = tf.dropout( splitted[ 1 ], rate = 0.6 ) 
rejoined = tf.concatenate( [ first_half, second_half ], axis = 0 )
```